# Extracting a string from a URL using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am debugging a piece of code where given the following string

"http://www.xyz.com/classid/17950142?type=mandatory"

It is supposed to extract the number shown between the `"classid/"` and `"?type=mandatory"` (i.e. the number 17950142

This is done using the following regular expressoin

```
Pattern.compile("^.*" + "http://www.xyz.com/classid/" + "([0-9]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

A couple of questions:

- The above reqular expression always returns NULL ie. no match when i pass the string http://www.xyz.com/classid/17950142?type=mandatory. What exactly does the "^.*" mean?
- Using the above expression, how does it know to skip the ? character and everything after it.

According a reference sheet i found by googling, ^.* basically means match any sequence of characters at the beginning of the string which in the above example would probably be null.

The expression itself will look something like this after the concatenation of the java strings has occurred.

```
 ^.*http://www.xyz.com/classid/([0-9]+)
```

Why does the above not match with the string `http://www.xyz.com/classid/17950142?type=mandatory`

Here is how i try to run the pattern in Java:

```
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(http://www.xyz.com/classid/17950142?type=mandatory);

        if(m.matches()) {
            return m.group(1);
        }
```

Update:

Thank you all that have answered. Interestingly, when i test this online using a regex tester it seems to work just as i was expecting. It is just not working in Java even though the expression and the string are the same.

See an example here
http://regexr.com?37pu3

Thanks

Comment: Why use regex for this? Get the index of the first `?` and get everything before it, then take everything after the last `/`. You can verify the existence of `classid` if you aren't sure that it's there.

Comment: The URL i provided is just an example so i can understand how the regular expression works. The actual URLs are in different formats and the number is not always after the ? character.

Comment: you are missing the `.*$` at the end of your Regex. Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `$` at the end of your regex. Try this:

```
String url = "http://www.xyz.com/classid/17950142?type=mandatory";

// ^.*http://www\.xyz\.com/classid/([0-9]+).*$
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.*" + "http://www\\.xyz\\.com/classid/" + "([0-9]+)" + ".*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);    

Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(url);

if (matcher.matches())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Notes:

- `^` is a special character meaning that the pattern will start to look at the beginning of your string
- `$` is the opposite from the `^`, meaning that it will look up until the end of the string
- The `.` and `?` characters on the URL needs to be escaped.
- A regex like `^http://www\.xyz\.com/classid/(\d+).*$` would make more sense, because you are checking the pattern from the beginning

Comment: Do you know why it works in this online test http://regexr.com?37pu3 (without the .$ at the end)? 

I am not interested in what is after the number so shouldnt it have matched to everything upto the last digit even without the .$

Comment: Not for sure, but if you are not interested on what comes after the captured code, you can just use a `.*`, without even the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

^.* is probably ^ - beginning of the string, .* - 0 or more of any character.

The expression matches everything up to a URL that is followed by a number: `([0-9]+)`

So it just means that it will match the string that ends with a number and doesn't care about anything that happens afterwards.

Comment: Thanks i understand those constants now but i still dont understand why there is no match :)

Comment: If you are referring to not getting a match in Java, could be because the symbols might be slightly different for RegExp under Java (like instead of ^, beginning of the string is $ or some such).  What I would suggest is just match for URL+num without including everything around.  That is, get rid of .* and beginning/end of string altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is not with the pattern, but I would suggest some small edits to that, as well.

1. Since you know you want periods between the elements of the domain name, you should escape those and make them literal periods. Whether or not you actually need ^.* depends a lot on how the URLs will appear in the strings you're matching against:

   ```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*http://www\.xyz\.com/classid/([0-9]+)");
   ```
2. Your use of the pattern should go something like this:

   ```
   Matcher m = p.matcher("http://www.xyz.com/classid/17950142?type=mandatory");
   ```

Then, you can continue with your conditional statement.

Working from your original approach, but generalizing the URL pattern, I was able to get this to grab the digits:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://\\S+/([0-9]+)\\?.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17950142?dopt=abstract");
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: I tried escaping the periods but that didnt make any difference. It only works if i use @Everton Agner suggestion to add a .*$ but im still not sure because i think the expression should match everything upto (and including) the digits and ignore everything else. See http://regexr.com?37pu3